How to find user place in DB
I have a peewee class with table for Users
class User(peewee.Model):
    """Class for Telegram user"""

    user_id = peewee.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    xp = peewee.IntegerField(default=0)

And a func for find user position in top of XP

async def get_user_position(self, user_id):
    """Get user position"""
        
    users = await orm.execute(
         (
             User.select(User.user_id)
            .group_by(User.user_id)
            .order_by(User.xp.desc()))
        .dicts())
        
    users = list(users)
        
    position = next((i+1 for i, player in enumerate(users) if player['user_id'] == user_id), None)
        
    if position == None:
        position = len(users) + 1
        
    return position


How can this be done using SQL only? Without using the next function, but only using the peewee library

Your user ids are unique. There's no need to group by user id because each user id can only have one row.

Oh, okay, thanks, I didn't notice it, copied it from another project when it was necessary.

You actually want to use window functions for this. You can use the RANK OVER to find this.
